# what is the height of a normal webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with this sample page on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/igeca4/edit

The height right now is `741px` however, at the bottom there is still some white space left.

I can keep doing trial and error witht the height pixels but whatever the user viewing the page has a large monitor.  My page will then look half empty from the bottom.

Is there a trick that can be used to take up all the height in a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard height of a webpage; you can't even assume the user has his/her browser maximized. If you are going to have a footer or page-bottom content, you want to make your page the full height of the browser.

Here is a link on having 100% height in CSS. Basically, you need to set the `html` and `body` objects to `height: 100%;`. (Most people don't think of `html` as an element to stylize.) You may need to make other adjustments based on the situation.

http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/?p=144

For more information, you can also refer to these. They should also be helpful:

- http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Hundred_Percent_Height
- http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/100-percent-height-interface

Answer (score 1):

Set `height:auto`.So that if you add something inside the content,it's height should be auto adjusted.

If you want to preload the height.then set `height:100%;`

Comment: this way the height is determined by elements I put inside it. I don't want this. I want it to be always full height of the screen irrelevant whether I'm adding elements inside or not

Answer (score 1):

Usually pages' content can scroll vertically.  In this case, you usually just worry about what content is "above the fold" - ie - in the user's screen prior to needing to scroll.  Usually I figure this is around 600px (768px tall minus address bar + tabs).  So you make sure the important stuff is within the top 600px.

Using a repeatable background image allows you to make sure your page (at least the design) fills the entire screen.

Other than those 2 things, there's really nothing you can do to "force" it to fit vertically unless you use Flash, which can re-size to the full window.